# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.models.wrappers'

Tags: python, gensim, lda, mallet, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to use LDA MAllet model. but I am facing with "No module named 'gensim.models.wrappers'" error.

- I have gensim installed and  ' gensim.models.LdaMulticore' works properly.
- Java developer’s kit is installed
- I have already downloaded mallet-2.0.8.zip and unzipped it on c:\ drive.
- This is the code I am trying to use:

  ```
  import os
  from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
  os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME':r'C:/mallet-2.0.8/'}) 
  mallet_path = r'C:/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'
  ```

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've installed the latest Gensim, 4.0.0 (as of late March, 2021), the `LdaMallet` model has been removed, along with a number of other tools which simply wrapped external tools/APIs.

You can see the note in the Gensim migration guide at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#15-removed-third-party-wrappers

If the use of that tool is essential to your project, you may be able to:

- install an older version of Gensim, such as 3.8.3 - though of course you'd then be missing the latest fixes & optimizations on any other Gensim models you're using
- extract the [`ldamallet.py` source code from that older version](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/release-3.8.3/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py) & update/move it to your own code for private use - dealing with whatever issues arise

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with Gensim's wrapper for MALLET but didn't want to downgrade. There is this new wrapper that seems to do the job pretty well.

https://github.com/maria-antoniak/little-mallet-wrapper/blob/master/demo.ipynb